# How to get Response data character set in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, character-encoding, shift-jis

Ajax Request:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo.html", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Here the ajax request get the data from demo.html file and then result variable contains the response data. So, how to check the character set type of 
data in result variable. Consider the `demo.html` is shift_jis. So, while doing ajax request the response data character set is same as `demo.html` character set or
it set as `utf-8` ?

Comment: read the response headers.

Comment: use `teleriks fiddler` for sending request to that url and check header of it

Answer (score 2):

Try to read header using xhr and read charset of header as below

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "demo.html", success: function(response,xhr,result){
    var cs = xhr.getResponseHeader("charset") ;
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```